# material table - stickyEnd and background not work

Tags: angular, angular-material

- when displaying the table, the "**sticky**" columns are well placed on the right
- when I dynamically add a row "ADD" button, the stiky columns does not appear on the new row. it is on the far right (by scrolling)
- and when we add a 2nd line, the stiky of the top line is placed well (it looks like the update of the table is not done, something like that)
- here is the **stackblitz**, to reproduce the problem :
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/lhm8bg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzzuH.jpg)